# How to use CSS3 selectors to select every even element

Tags: css, css-selectors

So this is the current code structure:

```
<section>
    <article>
        <p>Title</p>
        <p>Content</p>
    </article>

    <article>
        <p>Title</p>
        <p>Content</p>
    </article>

    <article>
        <p>Title</p>
        <p>Content</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

How do I get the first and the third title to `float:left`, and the second title to `float:right`...?

I tried this:

```
section article p:first-child:nth-child(even){
    float:right;
}
```

But I got no luck... :-(

Comment: You could do that, but you don't have to float the even ones.  They will naturally be on the same line as the float: left elements.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I'm just trying to get the selection logic sorted out... Floating elements seemed like the simplest distinction, though now that I think about it, coloring the text would've worked just as well... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
section article p:first-child {
    float: right;
}
section article:nth-child(even) p:first-child {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes! Exactly what I needed... Thanks mate.. :-) Will mark your post as the answer as soon as SO lets me...

Answer (score 1):

I think want you want is:

```
section article:nth-child(odd) p:first-child {
    float: left;
}

section article:nth-child(even) p:first-child {
    float: right;
}
```

You've actually selected the first child `<p>` that is also even, which, of course, can never happen.

Comment: Ah nice, you actually put me on the right track there.. Thanks... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to this

```
section article:nth-child(even){
    float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/cFTDj/3/

Comment: Ummm... it didn't work... I looked at your JSFiddle example, and all the Title's are on the left, while the Content is all on the right... >.<